# Difference between df$i and df[[i]] in R data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

When I loop over the column names of a data frame, removal of a column does not seem to work. Why is this the case?

```
df = data.frame(c(1:4), c(1:4))
names(df) = c('a', 'b')

for(i in colnames(df)){
    if(i == 'a'){
        print(i)
        df$i = NULL
    }
}
```

The dataframe `df` still contains column `a`.

Yet indexing the column using `[[i]]` works i.e:

```
df = data.frame(c(1:4), c(1:4))
names(df) = c('a', 'b')

for(i in colnames(df)){
    if(i == 'a'){
        print(i)
        df[[i]] = NULL
    }
}
```

Why does `[[]]` indexing work and `$` not work in this case?

Comment: Use `df[[i]]` instead of the column `i`

Comment: I see you edited your question. Did the explanation in my original answer not address this?

Comment: It did, thanks. Having received a downvote on the OP I wanted to further clarify the question...

Comment: @user123342 Gotcha. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df[,i] <- NULL` instead.

Using `df$i` is essentially telling R to create a new `NULL` column (named `'i'`), which leaves `df` in the original state.

Answer (score 4):

`df$i` is the column `i` of df. You have to use `df[[i]]` to access the column of `df` that has the value of variable `i`